# can not change google cloud platform default project to standard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have a stand alone google app script to be used as google sheet side bar.
It is currently attached to a *default* GCP and I want to change it to the *standard* GCP project I created.

I am now trying to set the GCP project number within the script editor settings.
but when I loading the `OAuth consent screen` configuration, is blocked due to permissions missing. attached screen capture.
[image]

Some more details:

1. I am the owner of both app script and the GCP project.
2. The GCP project has no organization, not sure exactly if I, at least currently, need it and how to set the organization. is it a must?
3. The final purpose is to put the app on the market. Until now I developed the app within a container spreadsheet, on  a different google account. setting the GCP project there was OK, and I could test the side bar with other spreadsheets than the container, ***Run -> Test as add-on*** in the legacy editor. Now I made the app script stand alone and load it to a new google account I created for the add on. This account is the owner of the app script and the GCP project.
4. I actually not sure what is the next step I need to take. I still need to test the add on, but I wanted to created a real environment. Maybe it is an issue of payment, an I am not a paying account, at least not yet.
5. Clicking on the left on the the  `OAuth consent screen` shows some more details:
   [image]

***Update:***

As per @JohnHanley suggestion, I currently activated the trial period google offers. The cloud project is now linked to the newly created billing account.
Now I can not access the app script.
Opening the project fails for some reason.
[image]

***Update 2:***

the issue of not being able to open the project script is solved by clearing browser cache as suggested [here](https://www.cbackup.com/articles/google-drive-unable-to-open-file.html#A1). As it happened (and solved) simultaneously in more than one browser, seems to me that it has something with setting the billing account.

However, I am now back to the original issue - trying to set the GCP project number to the app script project.
Although the GCP project is linked to billing account, I can not access the OAuth screen the message though is a bit different:

```
You are missing the following required permissions:
Project
resourcemanager.projects.get
```

Please advice,

Comment: create new project

Comment: @Kos What do you mean? I have already created a project, and I am trying to assign its number (i.e. project number) to the app script.

Comment: Verify that billing is set up and there are no errors related to billing payment details.

Comment: @JohnHanley so is it a payment issue? as I indicated, I didn't set any billing details yet...Also why did it work with my main account, where I also do not have billing details?

Comment: Google offers different tiers which have different requirements. Without billing, you can only use Always Free services. Your use case requires billing to be set up. Note: the details of which services require billing has been evolving in the past year. In summary, to do anything real with Google Cloud today, you must have billing setup.

Comment: Can you provide a set of reproduction steps?

Comment: @JohnHanley can you please see my post edit?

Comment: I do not recognize that error. What are the steps to get that error?

Comment: @JohnHanley I found a solution for not being able to load the script, but now back the the original issue. please see my update2.

Comment: Add the role **Project IAM Admin** to your account. The role name is **roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin**.